# Issue With Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm very new to learning Python and have been trying to install matplotlib. I believe I have successfully installed matplotlib because in the terminal it says that all the requirements were satisfied for downloading matplotlib for Python 3.10, but when I test it my typing import matplotlib into IDLE many error messages show up that can be seen in this image: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2OvV.png). I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand how I could fix this. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you created a file called `numbers.py` in your current working directory which is shadowing the import of the `numbers` library from Python core. Try running IDLE from a different directory or renaming the `numbers.py` file in your directory.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you created a file called numbers.py in your current working directory which is shadowing the import of the numbers library from Python core. Try running IDLE from a different directory or renaming the numbers.py file in your directory.

credits to @Craig

About the error in your numbers.py pay attention to your function: an integer is different from a list of integers.